# hive udf execution via shell script

Tags: shell, hive, udf

I have a Hive Udf that works well in hive terminal, What I want i want to execute it via shell script.
On hive terminal i am able to execute following commands :

```
use mashery_db;
add jar hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/nextdata_aggregations/custom_jar/readerCheck.jar;
add file hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/GeoLite2-City.mmdb;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION geoip AS 'com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF';
```

But when I am adding the above code in shell script

```
hive -e "use mashery_db;"
hive -e "add jar hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/nextdata_aggregations/custom_jar/readerCheck.jar;"
hive -e "add file hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/GeoLite2-City.mmdb;"
hive -e "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION geoip AS 'com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF';"
```

The 1st 'hive -e' works well and adds the jar but the last one create temporary function doesn't work. I am getting below error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:35 mismatched input 'com' expecting StringLiteral near 'AS' in create function statement
```

I have also tried with single quotes

```
hive -e "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION geoip AS 'com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF';"
```

then I am getting `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask`

```
FAILED: Class com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF not found
```

Does hive Udf supports shell script ,if it does whats wrong I am doing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try importing the jar and creating the function all in one call to hive.  i.e.  `hive -e "add jar path_to_jar/foo.jar; create temporary function foo as 'com.package.UDF';"`

Comment: @GoBrewers14 thanks it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each invocation of `hive -e` spawns a new process with a new hive shell that has no memory of what the previous one did, so hive 'forgets' where the UDF is... 
One solution is to chain them in just one command, but it's better form to put all your hive commands in a file (for instance "commands.hql") and use  `hive -f commands.hql` *instead* of `-e`.

File would look like this:

```
use mashery_db;
add jar hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/nextdata_aggregations/custom_jar/readerCheck.jar;
add file hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/GeoLite2-City.mmdb;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION geoip AS 'com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF';"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this to work with both `hive -e` and `hive -f`:

```
hive -e "use mashery_db;
add jar hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/nextdata_aggregations/custom_jar/readerCheck.jar;
add file hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/GeoLite2-City.mmdb;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION geoip AS 'com.mashery.nextdata.hive.udf.GeoIPGenericUDF';"
```

Creating them as a file and using `hive -f hive_file.hql` would work as well.